# Can I add a Flask server to an existing Node web app?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, http, flask

I've got a web app and some Python scripts I'd like to run on some inputted text. I looked around and it seems like Flask is the best solution for this, but wouldn't this mean I'd have two web servers?

So would I be starting the Flask server when the user submits some text, running the Python script, then stopping the Flask server? How would I do this? The app is JS/jQuery.

The other solution looks to be rewriting the Python into JavaScript which naturally I'm hesitant to do.

Comment: You need to give us more information about the webapp. In the title you say Node Webapp, but it your answer body you put JS/Jquery. If the web app is an Single Page Application you can server all related files using the same server that runs your python script.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Flask app that serves only as an API to your Node.js web app using the `flask-restful` extension. Link to the user guide [here](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You may run into problems with cross-origin resource sharing ([CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)) so you will probably need to pip install the `flask-cors` extension as well. Link [here](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cors/).

The following is a basic setup that should get you started:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Resource

# Import your python module containing the script
import your_python_scripts_module as scripts

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app, origins=['address of your node app'])
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('text')

class YourClass(Resource):
    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        # Invoke your text processing script here
        processed_text = scripts.text_processor(args['text'])
        response = {'data': processed_text}
        return response, 200

# This is where the routing is specified
api.add_resource(YourClass, '/your_api_endpoint')

if "__name__" == "__main__":
    app.run(host='address_of_flask_app')
```

As to your question about starting this server and closing it on demand from the Node app, I can't help you there (yet). I don't have any experience with that.

The setup above is for a simple flask module. You can set your app up as a package using the guide [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/).

Good luck!